# iphone epub reader how to change the font size/color programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, epub

I have seen many projects that reads epub files than parsing it to XML formats.

Some projects uses HTML to display the formatted  ftext in a web view

Is there any way possible way to change the color/size of a font?

I think some are including Java Script files but still not sure...

Any framework that rcan help for epub content reading and customiziing....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ePub uses XHTML & CSS for content, so most (if not all) ePub readers will use a UIWebView.

Changing the font color & size, then, is simply a matter of fiddling with said UIWebView's stylesheets, whether through JavaScript or altering the XHTML/CSS files directly.